# Lightsail instance works when you hit http://[domain].com, but not www.[domain].com, using Route 53 as DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I'm pretty new to DNS and this is the first time trying to connect a domain name to an IP, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I tried connecting both the www and non www NS records to the Lightsail name servers but only the non www option seems to be working. When I try to hit www.[domain].com, I get unresolved hostname. I also added an A record in each hosted zone that points directly to the IP and I'm not sure if they actually did anything, but I can only access the site from the IP or from http://[domain].com. I appreciate any help you guys can give me, hoping its something small.

[Here is an album containing my hosted zone and each zone's settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGaNv.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to use two separate hosted zone for www and the apex domain (non-www). You can have a single hosted zone and create resource record set for www and the apex domain using CNAME or Alias records. Since you already have an A-record for example.com, in the same hosted zone you can create a CNAME record for www.example.com and point it to example.com

Regardless, for the domain not found, it could be due to the TTL.

Hope this helps.

More information:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CNAMEFormat

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html#rrsets-values-basic-ttl

Answer (score 0):

if your website is working with example.com and not accessing [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

1:you need to set CNAME in DNS setting
redirect www to example.com not IP address, if you are redirect to IP address this will not work

2:check the apache2 configuration file
set servername: example.come
and ALIAS [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Additionally if you want to check the CNAME is working in apache run
dig [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) CNAME in commad line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).